# Mono resources.resx problem when porting (strange error in resx xml file on '</data>')

Tags: c#, .net, resources, mono, embedded-resource

So I have a C# app. It has some assets that are linked into it and are beeng embeded during compile time. App compiles and runs perfectly on windows. when testing for compatabilety with mono tells that all is correct. If I try to compile gives one error n xml file

```
/home/rupert/Desktop/CloudObserverLite(4)/CloudObserverLite/Properties/Resources.resx: Error: Error: Invalid ResX input.
Position: Line 123, Column 5.
Inner exception: value
 (CloudObserverLite)
```

And If we will look at resx xml

```
  ...<resheader name="writer">

    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>

  </resheader>

  <assembly alias="System.Windows.Forms" name="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />

  <data name="framework_4_5_0_17689_swz" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">

    <value>../assets/framework_4.5.0.17689.swz;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>

  </data>

  <data name="index_html" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">

    <value>../assets/index.html;System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;windows-1251</value>

  </data>...
```

line 123 would be first  `</data>` tag.

Here is all resx file if it can give any more info

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<root>

  <!-- 

    Microsoft ResX Schema 



    Version 2.0



    The primary goals of this format is to allow a simple XML format 

    that is mostly human readable. The generation and parsing of the 

    various data types are done through the TypeConverter classes 

    associated with the data types.



    Example:



    ... ado.net/XML headers & schema ...

    <resheader name="resmimetype">text/microsoft-resx</resheader>

    <resheader name="version">2.0</resheader>

    <resheader name="reader">System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, ...</resheader>

    <resheader name="writer">System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, ...</resheader>

    <data name="Name1"><value>this is my long string</value><comment>this is a comment</comment></data>

    <data name="Color1" type="System.Drawing.Color, System.Drawing">Blue</data>

    <data name="Bitmap1" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">

        <value>[base64 mime encoded serialized .NET Framework object]</value>

    </data>

    <data name="Icon1" type="System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">

        <value>[base64 mime encoded string representing a byte array form of the .NET Framework object]</value>

        <comment>This is a comment</comment>

    </data>



    There are any number of "resheader" rows that contain simple 

    name/value pairs.



    Each data row contains a name, and value. The row also contains a 

    type or mimetype. Type corresponds to a .NET class that support 

    text/value conversion through the TypeConverter architecture. 

    Classes that don't support this are serialized and stored with the 

    mimetype set.



    The mimetype is used for serialized objects, and tells the 

    ResXResourceReader how to depersist the object. This is currently not 

    extensible. For a given mimetype the value must be set accordingly:



    Note - application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64 is the format 

    that the ResXResourceWriter will generate, however the reader can 

    read any of the formats listed below.



    mimetype: application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64

    value   : The object must be serialized with 

            : System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter

            : and then encoded with base64 encoding.



    mimetype: application/x-microsoft.net.object.soap.base64

    value   : The object must be serialized with 

            : System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter

            : and then encoded with base64 encoding.



    mimetype: application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64

    value   : The object must be serialized into a byte array 

            : using a System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter

            : and then encoded with base64 encoding.

    -->

  <xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">

    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" />

    <xsd:element name="root" msdata:IsDataSet="true">

      <xsd:complexType>

        <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">

          <xsd:element name="metadata">

            <xsd:complexType>

              <xsd:sequence>

                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />

              </xsd:sequence>

              <xsd:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xsd:string" />

              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />

              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" />

              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />

            </xsd:complexType>

          </xsd:element>

          <xsd:element name="assembly">

            <xsd:complexType>

              <xsd:attribute name="alias" type="xsd:string" />

              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />

            </xsd:complexType>

          </xsd:element>

          <xsd:element name="data">

            <xsd:complexType>

              <xsd:sequence>

                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />

                <xsd:element name="comment" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />

              </xsd:sequence>

              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" msdata:Ordinal="1" />

              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="3" />

              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="4" />

              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />

            </xsd:complexType>

          </xsd:element>

          <xsd:element name="resheader">

            <xsd:complexType>

              <xsd:sequence>

                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />

              </xsd:sequence>

              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />

            </xsd:complexType>

          </xsd:element>

        </xsd:choice>

      </xsd:complexType>

    </xsd:element>

  </xsd:schema>

  <resheader name="resmimetype">

    <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>

  </resheader>

  <resheader name="version">

    <value>2.0</value>

  </resheader>

  <resheader name="reader">

    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>

  </resheader>

  <resheader name="writer">

    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>

  </resheader>

  <assembly alias="System.Windows.Forms" name="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />

  <data name="framework_4_5_0_17689_swz" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">

    <value>../assets/framework_4.5.0.17689.swz;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>

  </data>

  <data name="index_html" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">

    <value>../assets/index.html;System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;windows-1251</value>

  </data>

  <data name="osmf_1_0_0_16316_swz" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">

    <value>..\assets\osmf_1.0.0.16316.swz;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>

  </data>

  <data name="playerProductInstall_swf" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">

    <value>..\assets\playerproductinstall.swf;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>

  </data>

  <data name="player_html" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">

    <value>..\assets\player.html;System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;windows-1251</value>

  </data>

  <data name="rpc_4_5_0_17689_swz" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">

    <value>..\assets\rpc_4.5.0.17689.swz;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>

  </data>

  <data name="sparkskins_4_5_0_17689_swz" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">

    <value>..\assets\sparkskins_4.5.0.17689.swz;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>

  </data>

  <data name="spark_4_5_0_17689_swz" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">

    <value>..\assets\spark_4.5.0.17689.swz;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>

  </data>

  <data name="swfobject_js" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">

    <value>..\assets\swfobject.js;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>

  </data>

  <data name="textLayout_2_0_0_139_swz" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">

    <value>..\assets\textlayout_2.0.0.139.swz;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>

  </data>

  <data name="AC_OETags_js" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">

    <value>..\assets\ac_oetags.js;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>

  </data>

  <data name="history_historyFrame_html" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">

    <value>..\assets\history_historyframe.html;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>

  </data>

  <data name="history_history_css" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">

    <value>..\assets\history_history.css;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>

  </data>

  <data name="history_history_js" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">

    <value>..\assets\history_history.js;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>

  </data>

  <data name="player_swf" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">

    <value>..\assets\player.swf;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>

  </data> 

</root>
```

If we were looking at the project structure we would see:
[image]

Sorry I am new to mono - plase help.

Comment: Do you really have a comment in that node? Or was that just something you were experimenting with? <value><!--../assets/-->framework_4.5.0.17689.swz;System.Byte[], ....

Comment: sorry - it was experementation - with it or with out it does not work=( same error.

Comment: I've come across the same exactly problem when compiling GitExtensions on linux/mono.

Comment: I do not think this issue has anything to do with the resx file itself. This issue recently started happening on a project that has had the same resx file for over a year. The problem is likely stemming from elsewhere in the code

Comment: I guess the problem is about the encoding. Your file assets/index.html is created in encoding windows-1251, what's mentioned in the resx file. Consider re-saving the file in UTF-8.

Comment: BTW, you can safely compile on Windows using Microsoft .Net tools and then run compiled program with Mono on any Platform. Also try to build using Mono on Windows...

Comment: https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/3049

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit -> Preferences -> Projects -> Build and check the option "Compile projects using MSBuild / XBuild".

Comment: didn't help in my situation

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved with replacing all \ with / in all paths.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to embed the resources manually with dmcs:

```
dmcs -r:<libraries go here> -resource:<resource1> -resource:<resource2> -resource:<etc> *.cs -OUT:Program.exe
```

It's pretty cumbersome, I usually write out the long compilation string in a text editor (call it compilestring.txt say..), and them do something like:

```
comp=$(echo | cat compilestring.txt)
```

and then just type $comp to compile my project.

Hope this helps! (This is what I've had to resort to, after suffering similar problems with .resx files in linux and mono)

Answer (score -1):

i had this problem, but after opening the file create a little change ( like adding a new empty line or empty space) and save problems resolved. it is with file unicode. mono have this problem with solutions which has created by window.